# Google in app billing v3 view if subscription purchase was a success

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I am using this library: https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

When a subscription is purchased the `onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details)` method is not called.

How do I check if the subscription was successful?

Thanks

Edit:

Here is my button code to subscribe:

```
billingProcessor.subscribe(getActivity(), getString(R.string.str_monthly_sub_id));
```

Here us my init code:

```
billingProcessor = new BillingProcessor(context, getString(R.string.gdc_licence_key), this);
        billingProcessor.initialize();
```

Comment: show your initializing and subscription code

Comment: @Raza I edited my question with the code snippets

Comment: have you test your code to implement in activity not in fragment?

Comment: have you written onActivityResult to catch result after subscription?

Comment: @AbdurRehman it is in a fragment. Yes I did override the OnActivityResult method

Comment: where is onActivityResult ?

Comment: have you tried in activity?

Comment: @Think_Twice did you override onActivityResult in Fragment?

Comment: @Raza the onActivityResult is in the fragment

Answer (score 0):

if you are using fragment for this library, than there is something different, `onActivityResult` is not being called in Fragment for this you can use different approaches

1. you will need to override the `onActivityResult` method in activity and in this method call `super.onActivityResult()` to send result in fragment

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @NullableIntent data) {                           
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }
   ```
2. write this method is respected activity of fragment

   ```
   @Override 
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment fragmentObj = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yourFragmentId);
    fragmentObj.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }
   ```

then call `onActivityResult` in fragment!

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        if (!mBillingProcessor.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: how do i call the onActivityResult in the fragment? must I call it after the billingProcessor.subscribe(...) ? Also the fragment id is the parent id of the fragment layout right?

Comment: if you cannot manage code in fragment then you should implement in activity.